# How to Run two benchmarks in command line in gem5?

Tags: gem5

I am running two benchmarks in the command line by the following a script for Mi-bench, kindly confirm whether I am using the right script or not- I am separating two applications through semicolon; please help.

./build/X86/gem5.opt -d ./Mi-combination ./configs/example/se.py -c "/media/shukla/Windows/gem5_old/benchmar/MiBench/X86/network/dijkstra/dijkstra_small;/media/shukla/Windows/gem5_old/benchmar/MiBench/X86/network/patricia/patricia" -o "/media/shukla/Windows/gem5_old/benchmar/MiBench/X86/network/dijkstra/input.dat;/media/shukla/Windows/gem5_old/benchmar/MiBench/X86/network/patricia/small.udp" --cpu-type=MinorCPU  --cpu-clock=1GHz  --num-cpu=2 --caches --l2cache --l1d_size=32kB --l1i_size=32kB --l2_size=512kB --l1d_assoc=2 --l1i_assoc=2 --l2_assoc=2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Surendra, I'm not so familiar with SE, but a few tips: 1) if you make upstream threads as well, which is good, link to them from here: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16574.html 2) Explain what you want to achieve further: do you want them to run sequentially or in parallel? Why do you want to do this? 3) Familiarize yourself with Markdown syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and use code blocks for your code 4) Have you tried to grep the source / use PDB to see what is going on? What did you observe?

Comment: Hello Ciro... What you want to achieve further-I want to test running a benchmark alone: what is the performance in a multi-core system? which I configured vs running more than one program in the same multi-core system. I want to run two or more than two benchmark running in a multi-core system where the L2 Cache is shared amoong the cores. As I dont have script to run the benchmarks I am trying in command line.

Comment: I want to run benchmarks in parallel using two CPU core(If I would select two benchmarks)